# Forget previous view controllers with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I've got a `UINavigationController` which is created in my App Delegate.

After pushing a view controller, I would like the `navigationItem` of that view to 'forget' the previous view controller (stop displaying its back button), while still retaining the title of the newly-pushed view controller.

How could I achieve this? I've tried setting the `leftBarButtonItem` of the new view controller's navigationItem using

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

in `viewDidLoad`, but to no avail.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your New(second in stack) view controller hide the back Button by using navigationItem's method `setHidesBackButton:`.

Please try following code in your new view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // this hides navigation back button 
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
}
```

this will hide the back button and user could not able to navigate back.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something simple like that.